# Are there preprocessor defines to differentiate gcc and g++ code?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Are there preprocessor macros defined in the gcc and g++ compilers so that if I want to make my C code link to the C standard library or the C++ standard library? Something like:

someFile.c

```
#ifdef __CPP__
   #include <c++ library include>
#else
   #include <c library include>
```

I'm sure there are but a quick Google search didn't point me to right away and I'm sure someone is going to just post duplicate question, but in any case, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Note that it's a bad idea to compile a C file with a C++ compiler or vice versa , they are separate languages and there's a better way to do whatever you are trying to do

Comment: Also you can use the C version for the common headers in C++ (e.g. `#include <stdio.h>` is fine in C++)

Comment: Thanks for the concern, trust me code is going no where...just practicing some coding problems and trying it out on gcc and g++ compilers to see what works and what doesn't...

Comment: Thank you guys "#ifdef __cplusplus" works just fine!

Comment: Note that `g++` _is_ the gcc compiler. It's just a wrapper that after compiling tells the linker to link the C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 10):

In c++ you can you

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
```

eg if c++ code you want certain piece of code to be handled by compiler as c code you need to put that block in

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if there are `#define`s specific to GCC, but the C++ standard defines the symbol [`__cplusplus`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros). If that exists, then you are on a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the other answers, testing for the definition of the `__cplusplus` [predefined macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) will work:

> **__cplusplus** denotes the version of C++ standard that is being used, expands to
>   value 199711L (until C++11), 201103L (C++11), 201402L (C++14), or
>   201703L (C++17).

---

There is also a GCC specific macro which may be useful to you, `__GNUG__`. As outlined in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html):

> **__GNUG__**
>
> The GNU C++ compiler defines this. Testing it is equivalent to testing
>   (__GNUC__ && __cplusplus).

The linked GCC documentation also lists other macros defined by the different GNU compilers.

Answer (score 0):

In [6.10.8 Predefined macro names](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8) the C11 standard says (emphasis mine)

> The implementation **shall not** predefine the macro __cplusplus, nor shall it define it in any standard header.

I believe C++ mandates a conforming implementation to define that name, so you can use it to differentiate languages

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
/* c++ code */
#else
/* c code */
#endif
```